# cocos2D replace scene not initializing the class

Tags: ios, ios4, cocos2d-iphone, scene

I have two scenes (mainMenu) and other (HelloWorldScene). I'm able to switch the scenes using replace scene but after trying to load it second time it doesn't call the init method.

Here are my efforts so far.

```
//In my mainMenu.m

-(void)starting{

[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[HelloWorldLayer scene]];

}

//and in my HelloWorldScene.m file

-(void)goMain{

[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[mainMenu node]];

}
```

My Question is that how do I call the -(id)init method for that class while replacing the scene.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[mainMenu node]];
```

You're attempting to re-initialize an already existing object (mainMenu). If you want to use the same node (rather unusual I might add) then you would have to do it this way:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:mainMenu];
```

But since you're expecting init to be called you want to create a new instance of your main menu, that you achieve the same way as in [HelloWorldLayer scene] by sending the node message to the class itself (assuming MainMenu is the name of the class):

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[MainMenu node]];
```

Comment: I've imported the mainMenu.h but using that statement gives me an error (Unexpected Interface Name 'mainMenu': expected expression. I guess using that Node is required even if you don't want to initialize.

Answer (score 0):

The init method is generally designed to only be called when the object is first created. When you switch back to a scene, you can write your own -(void)switchBack method and call it to update the scene appropriately (chances are this will look very different to your init method as you won't want to re-add everything).

I had this issue, in the end I just created a new scene (and released the current one) when switching between scenes as it wasn't expensive for me. This was nice as I could release all the unused textures after a scene switch, and I didn't have to worry about updating things.

Answer (score 0):

The init Method was calling but some variables were not reseting, I had to reset them manually in a method.

by making a handle for HellowWorldLayer, we can call any methods defined inside of that class.

```
HelloWorldLayer *hw = [HelloWorldLayer node]; // This is how we create the handle.
[hw Testing]; // This is how we call any method inside.

[[CCDirector sharedDirector]replaceScene:[CCTransitionCrossFade transitionWithDuration:0.5 scene:hw]]; // Use that handle for changing the scene
```

Hopefully it will help someone.